# Having issues with downloading images

Tags: scrapy

I have built a simple scraper to download images from a website. Unfortunately, I am having issues with downloading these images such that nothing gets downloaded. I have searched online for similar issues, and have practiced these but it does not work for me. I have had this work in the past, so I cannot understand why it does not work now.

My scraper:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_exercises.items import ScrapyExercisesItem


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.meadowhall.co.uk/eatdrinkshop?page=1']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):

        content_page = response.xpath("//div[@class='view-content']//div")
        for cnt in content_page:

            link = cnt.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
            image_url = cnt.xpath(".//img//@src").get()
            
            if link != None:
                items = ScrapyExercisesItem()
                items['images'] = [image_url.split('?')[0]]
                yield items
```

pipelines.py

```
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
class DownfilesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        image_name: str = request.url.split("/")[-1]
        return image_name
```

settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy_exercises.pipelines.DownfilesPipeline': 55
    }
IMAGES_STORE = '.'
```

items.py:

```
class ScrapyExercisesItem(scrapy.Item):
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is add a few settings and include a results field in your item class

In your items.py file add this:

```
class ScrapyExercisesItem(scrapy.Item):
    images = scrapy.Field()
    results = scrapy.Field()
```

then in your settings.py file add this:

```
IMAGES_URLS_FIELD = 'images'
IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD = 'results'
```

Then try it again.

Comment: I missed that part in the documentation, thank you for sharing this does the job!